# How to have checkbox be toggled on "checkbox" column only, so row select don't toggle checkbox

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm using `multiselect: true` option on jqGrid setup.

The issue I'm having is when I click on any row, the checkbox get toggled.  How do I limit the toggling of checkbox to "checkbox" column only when clicking on that "checkbox" column.   I don't want the checkbox to be checked/unchecked when I click on 3rd column, 5th column, etc.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback `beforeSelectRow` allows to define specific rules for selection the row. It should return false to prevent the selection. The checkboxes from multiselect column have CSS class `"cbox"`. Thus the callback

```js
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    return $(e.target).hasClass("cbox");
}
```

should solve the problem.