# Jqgrid multi-select only clicking checkbox and disable row selection

Tags: javascript, jsp, jqgrid

I'm having scenario where I need to disable row selection in jqgrid and select multiple rows only if checkbox is selected. In addition to it, i also want to disable row selection because if the any of column contains js alert then there is alert if clicked on that column which is an xss attack. I have done selection only to checkbox using

```
multiboxonly: true
```

and disable row selection using

```
beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) { 
      return $(e.target).is('input[type=checkbox]');
}
```

Comment: You write about "xss attack". Do you use `autoencode: true` option of jqGrid to interpret the cell data as text instead of HTML fragments?

Comment: Yes used that also autoencode:true. But didn't get my required output. My usecase was to drag record from one jgrid and drop into other jgrid. I tried everything making mutliselect: multiselect and multiboxonly: true. But I got my solution by EOD. I tweaked some jgrid source code. I updated jquery.jstree.js and added jgrid.htmlEncode()     $.vakata.dnd.drag_start(e, { jstree : true, obj : e.target }, "<ins class='jstree-icon'></ins>" + $.jgrid.htmlEncode($(e.target).text()) );

Comment: Sorry, but all what you wrote about Drag and Drop of items from jstree to jqGrid is **absolutely another question**. To allow selection or rows only on click on the multselect-checkbow one need just implement the corresponding `beforeSelectRow` and nothing more. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33402985/315935) for example. All other your problems about  Drag and Drop of items from jstree or about some problems with xss attack are the subject of **separate questions**. It corresponds to the rules of stackoverflow. You should post your code and describe the problem in the questions.